# Understanding useNavigate, and useState in React to redirect user to an expected content

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im studying React and Javascript, and I'm makin a simple application.
I have a list of items, and I want to preview some of  the items properties (like name and age )
and make it possible to click in one of the item of the list to be redirect in another "specs" page in the app, where I can show the full information of the clicked item.

the following is the main component of the list:

```
import "./DummyItem.css";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Scientist({
  name,
  profession,
  accomplishment,
  dead,
  nobel,
}) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // const clickHandler = () => {
  //   navigate("/ItemSpecs"), { state: { name, profession } };
  // };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <li
        className="dummy-item"
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("/ItemSpecs"), { state: { name, profession } };
        }}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        <h5>{name}</h5>
        <p>profession: {profession}</p>
        <p>accomplishment: {accomplishment}</p>
        
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And  this is the list I made:

```
export default function PeopleList() {
  
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const ScientistsList = people
    .filter((scientist) => scientist.dead !== "true")
    .map((scientist) => (
      <Scientist
        name={scientist.name}
        profession={scientist.profession}
        accomplishment={scientist.accomplishment}
        dead={scientist.dead}
        
        // action={() => navigate("/scientist", { )}

        // useNavigate(2par: url, obj) with unique id in path
      />
    ));
```

So, now I'm struggling to write a function to handle the click to redirect in "specs" page.
Can anyone help me completing the code, so I'll understand the use of useNavigate and useState?
I mean, all I got for now is that I must use useNavigate and a unique id for each object in the array where my scientist information are stored, so I can redirect the user to the exact content he's expecting by the click.
Thank you in advance!

I've tried to consult the documentation, but I'm stuck.
My target is to display a list of items, with their little preview. Once you click in one of them, you'll be redirected in a new tab where you can access at full information of the item you clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `Link` react-router-component to navigate to spec page, instead of handling this with a function and using `useNavigate` hook.

then, you should use a dynamic route for the specs page you will navigate to.
**This is the best practice for your case**

```
// import Link
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

...
return (
<ul className="container">
      <li
        className="dummy-item"
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
       <Link to={specsId}>
           <h5>{name}</h5>
           <p>profession: {profession}</p>
           <p>accomplishment: {accomplishment}</p>
       </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
)
```

to learn the basics well, try learn tutorials:

- [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/DEFAULT.ASP)
- [Tutorial: Intro to React](https://legacy.reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)
- and more you can find them on internet.

Comment: Yup, when  you're stuck it means its time to go back to study...